# Espresso check content of next fragment in AndroidX Navigation

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-architecture-navigation

I'm testing the login feature with Espresso and it's correctly working as long as I check that the navigation action would bring the user to the fragment ith correct id.

```
@Test
fun loginLogout() {
    val fragmentArgs = bundleOf("numElements" to 0)
    val navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
    val titleScenario = launchFragmentInContainer<LoginFragment>(fragmentArgs, R.style.Theme_Ticketsmspayapp)

    titleScenario.onFragment { fragment ->
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.graph_home)
        Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), navController)
    }
    
    // Login details filling and confirming

    assertEquals(navController.currentDestination?.id, R.id.eventsFragment)

    onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.logout)).perform(ViewActions.click())
}
```

What I wanted to do next is to press the logout button contained in the fragment that's is being opened, but it looks like the `onView` is still referring to the view of the login fragment.
Is it possible for a single test to follow the view hiyerarchy of navigation graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TestNavHostController` specifically does not ever actually show any fragments - it relies on other test infrastructure (like `launchFragmentInContainer`) to actually create the single fragment under test.

Therefore it is expected that your single fragment under test will still be on screen even after you call `navigate` on the `TestNavHostController` - all that your test should be doing is validating that your `LoginFragment` is correctly calling `navigate` at the right time based on the input you have given it.

You do not need to test that a real `NavHostFragment` attached to a real `NavController` actually replaces your Fragment when you call `navigate` - that is *not* your code, but code that is already [covered by an extensive test suite](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:navigation/navigation-fragment/src/androidTest/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/).

However if you do want to write a full integration style test, then you would not use `TestNavHostController`, but instead test your full activity and use the actual `NavHostFragment` you have in your activity.